# Retrieve original image from thumbnail

Tags: c#, image

I have made a thumbnail of an image using `Image.GetThumbnailImage Method`.
Now I want to get the original image and display that original image to a different pictureBox when I click on the thumbnail (which is a different pictureBox).

Does anyone know how can we do that? I have search on the Internet and all I found is create a thumbnail, I didn't find any method to retrieve back the original image

Comment: sorry, but you have lost the original image. Cant get it back from the thumbnail.

Comment: It would be so cool if there was a magical `reconstructLargeImageFromDownscaledImage` function. Would be awfully magical though.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: yeah, I am doing a project in which I need to capture images from a camera and display it on the screen. I also have to store selectable images. I create thumbnail and put it in another pictureBox for stored images. That's why I want to retrieve the original image when click on the thumbnail :(

Comment: @HienTran Do you still have a copy of the original image?

Comment: @HienTran You should store data in some database with 2 versions of your Image (better for performance but the cost of storage is a little higher), 1 original version and 1 thumbnail version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have thumbnails which lead to an original version of the image, you need to at least keep and store the original version of the image.

When the user clicks the thumbnail, display the original version of the image that you stored.

### You cannot restore original images from a thumbnail

Given a thumbnail of an image, you can't expand it back into the original image. Scaling it down into a thumbnail is a destructive process which removes the vital information.

**Consider... given this thumbnail:**

[image: A very small image of the Mona Lisa]

**How could you recreate this image?**

[image: A much larger image of the Mona Lisa]

Most of the information in the larger image is missing in the thumbnail. The cracks in the paint aren't there in the thumbnail. Nor can you spot her veil, make out the background, see the white flecks on the canvas, or notice the waviness of her hair. You can't see the ripples of her dress nor the folds and creases in the fabric. In the thumbnail, all those things *no longer exist*: the scale down has destroyed all that information.

Trying to reconstruct the larger image from the smaller would be like akin to recreate a 20-page novel from a half-page summary of its major points: you can guess at how the author *might* have written it, but you'll never know word-for-word what it was originally.

The image of the Mona Lisa was from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mona_Lisa,_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci,_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg).